# Node fs opendir does not work with electron

Tags: electron, node.js-fs

I am using Electron and Node fs. I want to open a directory, but the directory does not open when fs.opendir is called. Other fs methods in the same file work as intented.

My code:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

function handleOpenDownloadLocation(event, location) {
    console.log('location: ', location);
    console.log('opening folder');
    fs.opendir(location, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}
```

This function is called and the location in the log is correct and I have verified that the directory/folder exists and is correct.

The location outputted:

`C:\Users\***********\Documents\desktopDownloads\Primorden External Playtest #2`

The only error message I get after 10 seconds of calling the method is:

`` (node:16420) Warning: Closing directory handle on garbage collection (Use `electron --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created) ``

Comment: What version of Node and Electron are you using?

Comment: @Arkellys v18.16.0

Answer (score 0):

I used the *shell* of electron to open the folder. opendir of node fs is not meant do anything with windows shell (or to trigger anything of windows like opening a directory in my case).

The code:

```js
const {
  ipcMain,
  dialog,
  app,
  shell
} = require('electron');

async function handleOpenDownloadLocation(event, location) {
  await shell.openPath(location);
}
```